# Redirect main domain to subdomain, but keep a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

Redirecting domain to subdomain seems easy using

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but how can I keep a single subfolder working without redirecting to subdomain?

so www.example.com/a-page AND example.com/any-page(.html or not) 
will be redirected to sub.example.com/any-page(.html or not)

BUT I want a subfolder (just a single one)  www.example.com/music/any-page(.html or not) AND example.com/music/any-page(.html or not) to work like that, to not be redirected (add an exception for it)

Note:
(.html or not) means that posts end in .html, pages don't (Wordpress) . not sure if it matters tho.

thank you

Comment: Does the sub dir use rewrites or are all the pags real pages?

Comment: no, the pages are not real pages, it's Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this to not redirect if it's the subdirectory otherwise redirect all other requests.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```